# How can I format date in ISO using Python?

Tags: python, date, iso

I have some dates which format is `d/m/yyyy` (e.g. 2/28/1987).
I would like to have it in the ISO format : 1987-02-28

I think we can do it that way, but it seems a little heavy:

```
str_date = '2/28/1987'
arr_str = re.split('/', str_date)
iso_date = arr_str[2]+'-'+arr_str[0][:2]+'-'+arr_str[1]
```

Is there another way to do it with Python?

Comment: I have huge list of dates so,my first option would be to copy/paste in a spreadsheet editor like LibreOffice and to change the format cell in order to set the right format but that does not work..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date().isoformat()
```

or, as running code:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str_date = '2/28/1987'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date().isoformat()
'1987-02-28'
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use the `datetime` module to parse it:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime.strptime('2/28/1987', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'1987-02-28'
```

Comment: `.isoformat()` on dates uses the same formatting string OOTB. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is very nearly how I would write it, the only major improvement I can suggest is using plain old `split` instead of `re.split`, since you do not need a regular expression:

```
arr_str = str_date.split('/')
```

If you needed to do anything more complicated like that I would recommend [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime), but that's significantly *more* expensive than string bashing.